# Remove ip address leading zeros with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I convert my 010.017.007.152 style addresses (for easy database sorting) to 10.17.7.152 for display and hyperlinks using Javascript?

Samples:
010.064.214.210
010.064.000.150
010.064.017.001
127.000.0.001
10.0.00.000

Many thanks.

Comment: You just have to remove the leading zero.

Comment: Ha, ha! But I want Javascript to do it, not me. Thanks for joining in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function fix_ip(ip) { return ip.split(".").map(Number).join("."); }
```

JSFiddle (h/t @DavidThomas): http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c4EMy/

Comment: Nice idea mapping to the Number constructor!

Comment: That's where I was going, may I offer you a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c4EMy/)? =)

Comment: Mapping constructors is nice: `var a=[undefined,'abc',1,2,'',null,3]; a.filter(Boolean); //=> ['abc',1,2,3]`

Comment: map might not work on IE < 8 without using a library, like jquery or underscore - very nice solution though

Comment: Nirk's solution is my favourite. Thanks.

Comment: @Transistor if it is your favourite, you should mark it as the accepted answer (the big tick near the vote count for the answer)

Comment: Thanks, Billy. I thought my reputation wasn't high enough. Done.

Answer (score 3):

With regex, you can make replacements to many patterns. Something like this could work...

```
var ip = "010.064.214.210"
var formatted = ip.replace(/(^|\.)0+(\d)/g, '$1$2')
console.log(formatted)
```

Regex in plain english...

```
/         # start regex
(^|\.)    # start of string, or a full stop, captured in first group referred to in replacement as $1
0+        # one or more 0s
(\d)      # any digit, captured in second group, referred to in replacement as $2
/g        # end regex, and flag as global replacement
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using string manipulation and conversion to integers. Looks ugly compared to the [regex solution by Billy Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938349/825789), but works:

```
var ip = "010.064.000.150".split('.').map(function(octet){
    return parseInt(octet, 10);
}).join('.');
```

Or, a tiny bit cleaner:

```
var ip = "010.064.000.150".split('.').map(function(octet){
    return +octet;
}).join('.');
```

---

[Nirk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938394/825789) uses a similar method, and is even shorter, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
    var ip = " 010.017.007.152";
    var numbers = ip.split(".");
    var finalIp = parseInt(numbers[0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
        finalIp += "."+parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }

    console.log(finalIp);
```